# Headless CMS still exposes content?

Tags: 8

I set up a Drupal 8 CMS  at `http://mydrupalsite.com/`.I successfully created a RESTFul API at `http://mydrupalsite.com/api/v1/newsarticles`.  My API pulls content by doing something like

```
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
    ->condition('type', 'newsarticles')
    ->condition('status', NODE_PUBLISHED)
    ->range(0, 1);
```

However, I noticed that I can still see content at `http://mydrupalsite.com/node/<integer>`.   What's the best way for my headless CMS to NOT expose content other than to:

- administrators who need to edit the content
- expose content only via the API end points

Comment: Disallow access?

Comment: Can you elaborate?  You mean through robots text file?  Or htaccess?  If htaccess, how do you allow administrators to still view it so that they can edit it?

Comment: If you want editors to be able to edit it through a browser, then it's not headless.

Comment: I tried adding the rule `Redirect 301 /node/(\d+) /node/$1/edit?destination=/admin/content` to my .htaccess but it doesn't seem to take any effect.  Any idea what's wrong with it?

Comment: @Jaypan ok I change my requirement.  I don't want administrators to go to `/node/(\d+)`, but I still want them to be able to easily click to the CMS page that allows them to edit the node.  Right now, the first column in the table of the page `/admin/content` has links that take you to `/node/(\d+)`.

Comment: Have you considered taking the "access content" permission away from anon users? That should ensure only logged-in users will see content.